# Multi-Site clustering on Windows 2012 for SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, clustering

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.  We are trying to do a proof of concept for a 3 node multi-site cluster on Windows Server 2012 R2 for our SQL Server environment.  There will be two different subnets, one in each datacenter.  I have come across many articles telling me how to set up the cluster but what I'm having trouble with is the IP address for the cluster.

Does anyone know how I can add the IP from the second datacenter into the cluster?  I have come across articles that mention I would have to add an OR dependency for the second IP but I am not sure how to make this IP even appear as an option to add.  Am I supposed to have the IP address added to the NIC?

I hope my questions aren't confusing and that I'm conveying them clearly.

Answer (score 3):

The cluster will pickup all the different subnets you have configured on your NICs.

Once a server with NICs that have IP addresses of the 2nd subnet is included in the cluster you will be asked to add an IP for each subnet for each role as you add them to the cluster.

Comment: So does that mean for each nic on the nodes, we would need the IP for all 3 nodes that will be in the cluster?  So for example, NODE1 will have IP for the server itself, an IP for the cluster name in DataCenter1 and the IP for the cluster name in DataCenter2?

Comment: The nodes need their own IP for the subnet they are in. Each cluster or role name will have an IP for each subnet. The DNS record points to the cluster/role name and then the cluster decides which cluster IP that cluster/role name points to.